# Esp8266 crash after object instantiation

Tags: c++, iot, esp8266

The following code worked out for a couple of days. Right now, the Esp8266 crashes before entering the setup() function. I have tried a couple of boards. I have also checked the power supply. If the instantiation `BME280 bme;` in **app.ino** is commented out, there's no crash anymore. So I guess there's something wrong in the class definition and implementation of bme280.hpp. Would be great if someone could have a look into the code. Many thanks in advance.

**app.ino**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "bme280.hpp"
#include "homepage.hpp"

// Initialize Wifi connection to the router
const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
WiFiClientSecure client;
BME280 bme;
Homepage html;

void setup() {

  Wire.begin(0, 2);
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println('\n');
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);             
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid); Serial.println(" ...");

  int i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(++i); Serial.print(' ');
  }

  Serial.println('\n');
  Serial.println("Connection established!");  
  Serial.print("IP address:\t");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());         

  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() 
{
  server.handleClient();
}

void handle_OnConnect()
{
  // Get new sensor measurements
  BME280::Data sensor_data = bme.getData(); 
  // Send sensor measurements to server
  server.send(200, "text/html", html.sendHTML(&sensor_data));
}

void handle_NotFound()
{
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

**bme280.hpp**

```
#ifndef BME280_H
#define BME280_H
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "cactus_io_BME280_I2C.h"
#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

class BME280
{
  public:
    BME280();
    struct Data {float humidity, temperature, pressure, altitude;};
    Data getData();
  private:
    float temperature;
    float humidity;
    float pressure;
    float altitude;    
    BME280_I2C bme;  
    void readData();
};

#endif
```

**bme280.cpp**

```
#include "bme280.hpp"

BME280::BME280()
  : bme(0x76)
{
    if (!bme.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Es konnte kein BME280 Sensor gefunden werden!");
    Serial.println("Bitte überprüfen Sie die Verkabelung!");
    while (1);
  }
}

BME280::Data BME280::getData()
{
  BME280::Data d;
  readData();
  d.humidity = humidity;
  d.temperature = temperature;
  d.pressure = pressure;
  d.altitude = altitude;
  return d;
}

void BME280::readData()
{
  bme.readSensor();
  humidity = bme.getHumidity();
  temperature = bme.getTemperature_C();
  pressure = bme.getPressure_HP();
  altitude = 44330.0F * (1.0F - pow((pressure / SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA), (1.0F / 5.225F)));
}
```

Comment: What is `sendHTML` function and what is `BME280_I2C`?

Comment: What calls the `setup` function?

Comment: ```BME_I2C``` is an object from the BME_I2C class. Setup is a standard function in the Arduino framework and will be called once during initialization.

Comment: ```sendHTML``` is sending an HTML string including the sensor values and can be accessed via typing the IP address of the local Webserver.

Comment: Could any of your global variables be suffering from a case of premature death? For example, a [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) between `BME280` and `Serial`?

Comment: I don't know my Arduino at all, so which runs first? `setup()`  or `BME280 bme;`? If `bme` is constructed first, `Serial`'s not set up yet.

Comment: I guess the software watchdog bites because the setup loop might take too long. Maybe due to too much object instances beforehand. I guess the timeout is somewhere between 1.5 and 2.5 seconds. But normally, this timeout shouldn't be triggered with this implementation.

Comment: You should be be able to test that theory with a wee-little test program that sleeps for a couple seconds in an otherwise empty `setup` function.

Comment: @Florian oh sorry, I mean, I know what they are, what I meant is, could you post the declaration of bme280_i2c and its definition and the definition of sendHTML function? I'm asking because in the code you have posted there is nothing crashable

Comment: Confirm that the BME280 is still responding over the I2C bus. The code in to constructor goes into an infinite loop if it fails to initialize - which would cause a watchdog timer failure. Try outputting an error message there instead. It’ll need to call Serial,begin first.